# Codeigniter pagination variable undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm new in CodeIgniter Framework, I'm trying to display the result with pagination but I'm having a pagination variable `undefined`.

Here is my **Model**:

```
class Campaign_model extends  CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_campaign_lists($limit, $start) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ch_campaigns LIMIT '.$limit.', '.$start;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
class Pagination extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('campaign_model');
}

public function index() {

    //pagination settings
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('pagination/index');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('ch_campaigns');
    $config['per_page'] = "5";
    $config["uri_segment"] = 1;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

    //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 0;

    //call the model function to get the department data
    $data['campaignlist'] = $this->campaign_model->get_campaign_list($config["per_page"], $data['page']);           

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //load the department_view
    $this->load->view('campaign_view',$data);
}
}
```

and the **View**:

```
<div class="main-container-footer text-center">
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>
</div>
```

im trying to fix this error for awhile now but still no luck. please help me.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: pagination
Filename: views/campaign_view.php
Line Number: 26
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cheching\application\views\campaign_view.php
Line: 26
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cheching\application\controllers\Content.php
Line: 11
Function: view
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cheching\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: what's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @low_rents updated the question.

Comment: @PedroOrdonez, it seems reasonable expect such kind of error message. Looking at your code, you're not defining `$pagination` variable anywhere while you're trying to use it in ` <?php echo $pagination; ?>`.

Comment: @EddieC. yes i know but im only following this tutorial [link]http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/04/php-codeigniter-pagination-twitter-bootstrap-styles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add at the beginning of controller's method `index()` the following line:

```
public function index() {

    $data = array();

    // [...] index method implementation.
}
```

Comment: What if you change the line:
`$this->load->view('campaign_view',$data);` into
`print var_export($data, true); $this->load->view('campaign_view',$data);` ? What is the output in console?

Comment: I think it's impossibile that `print var_export($data, true);` is not producing any output. It seems reasonable to me that you're doing some general mistake which is preventing to get it correclty (in codiging, upload, etc.)

Comment: sorry there is a output now

`array ( 'page' => 'index', 'campaignlist' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'c_id' => '1', 'c_campaign_name' => 'sample', 'c_customer_name' => '', 'c_start_date' => '', 'c_end_date' => '', 'c_status' => '', 'c_date_created' => '0000-00-00', 'c_date_modified' => '0000-00-00', )), ), 'pagination' => '', )`

Comment: there is no error now but the pagination still not showing

Comment: Ok so you solved the problem :). Now you have a new question: "Why pagination is not showing"? I guess the answer is that `create_links()` function display the pagination only when `ceil(total_rows/per_page) > 1`. If you print `$config['total_rows']` and `$config['per_page']` you can check my supposition.

Comment: added additional row still the pagination is not showing.

Comment: Pedro, I really thing this is another question and you should handle it separately (maybe in a different and specific question or outside of StackOverflow). It's going to be a remote debugging session :).

Comment: ok. thanks for your time and for teaching me how to use print var_export(); :)